# Upsample an Rx observable based on another

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I am new in reactive extensions, so please excuse my ignorance. I have two observable objects `obj1` and `obj2` that return items. In a specific time windows T(buffer I suppose) I want to upsample the sparsest item sequence. 
See, a schematic example.

```
            Time of returned objects   
        obj1   t1  t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 ...   
        obj2  t1         t2       t3 ...
     os_obj2   t1  t1 t2 t2 t2 t3 ...   
 time_window <-----T-----><-----T----->
```

In the upsampled procedure, we place `obj2` returned items in the same place(time) the items of `obj1` exist.

The choice of what `obj2` item we should replicate on a specific `obj1` item time depends on which `obj2` item is closer on the specific `obj1` item time.

Could you please suggest a way (possible functions, or a pipeline of functions) to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Rx generally deals with items as they come in. It can't really make a prediction about the future, unless you set up some sort of predictive stream. At t3 on your diagram, how should this function know that the slower observable is about to change?

Comment: @Shlomo thanks for the interest. I have made a small change in my question. I think trying to do this is a buffer is possible now. Am I right? Any comments suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: This does seem like you want some form of time travel. You can't possibly produce values from the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** I just noticed that you want to emit items that were not emitted previously by any other observables. This cannot be achieved as it requires foreseeing the future.

If `obj2` emits predictable items at regular times, then you can do something. Make `obj2` emit those items a half a period earlier, so you can just use the latest items from `obj2`, and don't need to predict future items.

The following sample will emit the latest items from `obj2`, at emit times of `obj1`. The easiest is to use [`Observable.withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md).

```js
var obj1 = Rx.Observable.interval(500).map(x => "obj1." + x).take(10);
var obj2 = Rx.Observable.interval(300).map(x => "obj2." + x).take(10);

obj2.withLatestFrom(obj1).pluck(1).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.11/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

**PS:** At first I thought [`sample`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sample.md) can be used, but it didn't work for me for oversampling.

Answer (score 1):

Each value in an observable stream has two elements: The time in which it appears, and the value. So let's alter your schematic slightly:

```
Timeline  0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8...
XObserve  x0-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8...
YObserve  y0-------y1-------y2------...
```

So we have two observables, one emits a value every second (for simplicity, let's say the timeline is a second scale), the other emits a value every three seconds. Given all that, do you want a third stream `ZObserve` to use an upsampling technique to produce values for the Y stream at the rate of the X stream, like so?

```
Timeline  0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8-...
XObserve  x0-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8...
YObserve  y0-------y1-------y2------...
ZObserve  y0-y0-y1-y1-y1-y2-y2-y2-??...
```

As you can see the value for `ZObserve` at `T8` is `??` because I have no idea what it is. I also don't see how at `T2` and `T5` I could have predicted what the next value from the Y stream is going to be. If there are reliable rules for what they will be, then we can code it accordingly, generate a new stream `PredictedY`, and use `WithLatestFrom` as @Tamas suggested to produce the Z stream.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use Operator [CombineLatest](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#CombineLatest) and to maybe Sample afterwards